# Ultisnips - trigger expansion only at end of line

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

I have a snippet for C-like languages that looks like this:

```
snippet { "braces"
{
    $0
}
endsnippet
```

I would like to restrict this snippet to expand only if the tab trigger occurs at the end of the line.

I tried to use a regex trigger instead (`{$`) without success. To quote the documentation: "The snippet is expanded if the recently typed characters match the regular expression".

Comment: A regex snippet will not work because "The snippet is expanded if the *recently typed characters* match the regular expression." So it will always match `/{$/` even if it's in the middle of the line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured out how to implement it as a custom context snippet:

```
snippet { "braces" "snip.column == len(snip.buffer[snip.line]) - 1" e
{
    $0
}
endsnippet
```